# RESTful API: build URLs for resource that can be identified by two different string properties

Tags: java, rest

I am designing a Spring web application that manages opportunities for sales persons. Naturally I have opportunities DB entity with an internal unique identifier.
The web application also interfaces with CRM systems like Salesforce, Hubspot, etc. We maintain the identifier of the opportunity in the CRM system as a property of our opportunity. we call this property `externalIdentifier`.

The requirement of the RESTful api is to allow access to opportunity by either internal or external identifier. both of these properties are defined as String. I understand that the same opportunity resource will have two URLs. I must have a way to tell if the path variable signifies an internal or external identifier.

this design:

```
/opportunities/{internal-id}
/opportunities/{external-id}
```

is basically the same URL and the web server does not know which identifier is used. the path must be different.

so far I have come up with the following

```
/opportunities/{internal-id}
/opportunities/external/{external-id}
```

does this make sense? does it conforms to RESTful convention?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> does this make sense? does it conforms to RESTful convention?

It's fine.  REST doesn't care what spelling conventions you use for your resource identifiers.

It might make things easier for the humans in your system if you were to choose parallel spellings

```
/opportunities/internal/{internal-id}
/opportunities/external/{external-id}
```